# extracting results from a for loop

Tags: r, events

i am currently working on creating a program on event studies in R. I have a large set of events and have used this code to create a for loop which basically runs the regression n number times where n is the number of events i have in my dataset. 
i am really struggling in trying to get the results from each regression into a dataframe and was wondering if anyone would have an idea how to do it. my code is here -

```
#Reading in the data from excel
AllData <- read.xlsx("eventstudy.xlsx", 1)
EventDates <- read.xlsx("eventstudy.xlsx", 2)
Event <- list()

p <- for(i in 1:length(EventDates$Date.of.notice.)) {
        Event[[i]] <- evReturn(y = AllData, 
                               firm = as.character(EventDates$Bank.[i]), 
                               y.date = "date",
                               index = "s.p500", 
                               est.win = 252, 
                               digits = 3, 
                               event.date = as.character( EventDates$Date.of.notice.[i] ), 
                               event.win = 30)
       Event[[i]]
       plot(Event[[i]])
       print(Event[[i]])  
    }

    d <- matrix(nrow=20, ncol=3) 

    for (i in 1:20) { 
       d[i,] <- c(i+i, i*i, i/1)
    }
```

Comment: Try `do.call(rbind, Event)`

Comment: Thanks Oliver , when I do that , i get NULL as a result. is there any other way out ?